# Doctrine 2 - how to SQL ORDER joined table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to retrieve from database news and comments tables. This tables are related correctly.
The problem is that I also want to ORDER comments table. Everything works include ordering(with ASC and DESC).

PHP CODE

```
$query = $doctrine->getManager()
->createQuery(
      'SELECT news FROM BlogAdminBundle:News news
       JOIN news.comments comments
       WHERE news.id = :id
       AND news.date_active < :date ORDER BY comments.dateAdd DESC'
)->setParameters(array('date' => new \DateTime(), 'id' => $news_id));

$fetched_news = $query->getSingleResult();
return array('fetched_news' => $fetched_news);
```

TWIG CODE

```
{% for comment in fetched_news.comments %}
//displaying data
{% endfor %}
```

I know that I can retrieve separately news table and comments table, but idea to include this in one request is better idea.

Anyone want to help ?:)

Comment: What's the issue, if everything works and in your query you ordered by comments?

Comment: Well, it seems like you want to fetch only ONE news article, with the specific ID, and all of it's comments with ordering, right?

You should really reconsider this approach, because if you want only one result - one news article - that's okay, but if you have multiple "rows" of comments (so that you can run a for loop in the view), you will have joined news article data for each comment row as well. 

I don't see a benefit for this approach. 
It would be much easier to write a simple get method on your news entity such as "getComments", and loop them like so.

Might even exist by default.

Comment: That's right @dootzky, I want to do this. So I see that the best option is to separately get News and Comments(by a special method which should be used to all special ordered requests). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work, assuming...

News entity looks something like this:

```
/**
 * News
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="News")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class News {
...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="comment", mappedBy="news", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"dateAdd" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $comments;
...
}
```

Controller includes `$news = $em->getRepository("YourBundle:News")->find($id);`

And template includes (assumes column named `item` in News entity and column named `comment` in Comment entity):

```
{% for event in news %}
    {{ event.item }}
    {% for piece in event.comments %}
        {{ piece.comment }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```